# Is gnome-calendar usable, and how do I use it?

Tags: gnome, calendar

I just found this: https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/Apps/Calendar which seems nice! Is this something that I can use? How do I install it?

Answer (score 1):

It was under in heavy development. The development seems to have halted 9 months ago. However if you are interested you can compile from git & create a binary package for it.

There is a new calendar app (written in vala) from Yorba called California. It will soon be available in Yorba's daily build ppa.

http://blogs.gnome.org/jnelson/2014/03/21/introducing-california-a-new-gnome-3-calendar/